# Relación de Laravel devuelve dato erróneo en algunos casos

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

Tengo 2 tablas en Laravel las cuales tienen sus relaciones y me devuelven los datos correctamente en la mayoria de los casos, las esctructuras son algo asi

```
Tabla Trabajadores
----------
ConsecutivoNomina | ConsecutivoTrabajador | Nombres | Apellidos
```

Esta tabla en campo `ConsecutivoNomina` posee el valor `1` para la mayoria de los empleados y `ConsecutivoTrabajador` seria el campo autoincrementable +1, el problema viene siendo cuando un trabajador tiene `2` en el campo `ConsecutivoNomina`.

Mi segunda tabla tiene esta estructura

```
Tabla Cargos
----------
ConsecutivoNomina | ConsecutivoTrabajador | Cargo
```

Al igual que la anterior `ConsecutivoNomina` posee el valor `1` para la mayoria y `ConsecutivoTrabajador` seria el campo autoincrementable +1

Cuando un empleado en la tabla `Trabajadores` tiene `2` en `ConsecutivoNomina` su relación con la tabla de `Cargos` deberia devolver los datos para el `ConsecutivoNomina` 2 y su numero en `ConsecutivoTrabajador`, por ejemeplo

```
Tabla Trabajadores
----------
ConsecutivoNomina | ConsecutivoTrabajador | Nombres | Apellidos

----------

1 | 1 | Juan  | Gomez
2 | 1 | Pedro | Perez



Tabla Cargos
----------
ConsecutivoNomina | ConsecutivoTrabajador | Cargo

----------

1 | 1 | Empleado
2 | 1 | Gerente
```

Asi reparte los datos la base de datos, si `ConsecutivoNomina` es `1` `ConsecutivoTrabajador` va aumentando +1, pero si es `2` empieza desde el 1 nuevamente solo para los que tienen valor `2` en `ConsecutivoNomina`

En la mayoria de los casos me devuelve bien los datos, por ejemplo

```
$users = Empleado::where([['Situacion', '0'], ['ConsecutivoNomina', '1']])->get();

foreach($users as $user){
   $user->posicion->cargo
}
```

Esto funciona perfectamente, pero al queres hacer los mismo para los trabajadores con `ConsecutivoNomina` 2 de la siguiente manera

```
$users = Empleado::where([['Situacion', '0'], ['ConsecutivoNomina', '2']])->get();

foreach($users as $user){
   $user->posicion->cargo
}
```

En la relacion en vez de regresarme `Gerente` que es lo que corresponde para este usuario, me regresa `Empleado`, ya que tanto `Gerente` como `Empleado` comparten el mismo valor de `ConsecutivoTrabajador` en este caso seria por ejemplo `1`, mi duda es como hago para que en mi relación me traiga `Gerente` o el dato que corresponda cuando el trabajador tenga `2` en `ConsecutivoNomina`.

Supongo que en este momento me regresa mal el dato, ya que ambos, comparte el mismo valor de `CosecutivoTrabajador` y me regresa el primero que encuentra, pero necesito que me regrese en la tabla de cargos el valor de `ConsecutivoTrabajador = 1`, pero con `ConsecutivoNomina = 2`

Mis modelos

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'fldTimeStamp'
    ];

    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

    protected $table      = 'IGNom_Trabajador';

    protected $primaryKey = 'Consecutivo_Trabajador';

    public function client(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client', 'ConsecutivoDpto');

    }

    public function position(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Position', 'ConsecutivoTrabajador');

    }

}
```

---

```
class Position extends Model
{

    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';

    protected $table      = 'IGNom_RNET';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ConsecutivoTrabajador';

    public function employee(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');

    }
}
```

Comment: has intentado asi? `$users = Empleado::where('Situacion', '0')->where('ConsecutivoNomina', '2')->get();` + el 0 y el 2 son enteros? o string? en la base de datos

Comment: @JeffCasino Si he intentado eso, pero me regresa el valor incorrecto, el 0 y 2 son enteros

Comment: tomando esto "pero necesito que me regrese en la tabla de cargos el valor de ConsecutivoTrabajador = 1, pero con ConsecutivoNomina = 2" prueba esto `$users = Empleado::where('ConsecutivoTrabajador', 1)->where('ConsecutivoNomina', 2)->get();`

Comment: el modelo Empleado a que tabla va? + si son enteros, los valores deben ir sin comillas en los where

Comment: El modelo va a la tabla de cargos, esa consulta que me das ya la he probado y regresa el valor incorrecto, en la relacion devuelve como si fuera `ConsecutivoNomina 1` y no 2

Comment: mmm, puedes incluir en la pregunta el modelo? para ver las relaciones

Comment: @JeffCasino Ya los inclui

Comment: Prueba esto `$users = Empleado::where([['Situacion', '0'], ['ConsecutivoNomina', '1']])->whereHas('position', function($q){
            $q->where('position.ConsecutivoTrabajador', 2);
        }>get();`

Comment: @JeffCasino No funciona, me dio este erro `The multi-part identifier "position.ConsecutivoNomina" could not be bound. `, modifique `postion.ConsecutivoTrabajador` por `IGNom_RNET.ConsecutivoTrabajador`, pero me da el mismo resulta que siempre

Comment: a ver, intentare replicarlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95562/discussion-between-jeffcasino-and-edwin-aquino).